# can't use odoo from mobile unsupported odoo version

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to use the odoo mobile application (android):
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.odoo.mobile

I enter server IP and port, login and password but I can't log in
the app displays: "unsupported odoo version" message

I am using odoo 10 community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the app [description](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.odoo.mobile) on Google Play Store states:

> Supported Versions:
>
> - Odoo 10.0 (Enterprise)
> - Odoo   9.0 (Enterprise) - Some legacy features may not be supported

Answer (score 1):

I'm using odoo mobile with 11.0 and it's works perfectly, you find the source code of the app on github (https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework) , clone it and import it in android studio